# Mulitcolor LED circuit riddle

Tags: led, circuit-analysis

On a skiing trip I saw a string of solar powered multicolored lights that someone had thrown in a tree such as this:

[image]

All the lights were initially lit.
As the night progressed I noticed that the red LEDs darkened, then the green and only blue remained. This runs counter to my intuition which would suggest that the battery of the circuit would run lower (and probably no dc-dc converter since its a cheap chinese string of lights).

[image]

My question is: How would a progressive drop in voltage from a battery produce the red, then green then blue lights darkening? (When it should be the other way 'round if they are in parallel)

What kind of circuit from a battery with a dropping voltage could produce this result?

Comment: all red LED's have two diodes extra in series, all green LED's have one diode extra in series and the blue LED's are unchanged. Riddle solved!

Comment: Regular-efficiency reds and oranges, high-efficiency greens and blues. They're all just as powered, but only the HE LEDs show anything at that current.

Comment: Are they connected in series, like tree reds, two green single blue to the same Vcc? Highly counter-intuitive.

Comment: I blame an aurora borealis.

Comment: I blame the hot apple cider....

Comment: I think you can't make an assumption that these particular red LEDs are made on AlInGaP technology. I recently have played with a garden solar light from WalMart for 97c, and it has a nearly-white LED (obviously some luminophore-based) running at under 2V, and very bright at 2 mA. These days examining Chinese devices is more like reverse engineering of alien technology, you never know.

Comment: Really, without so much more information it is impossible to say what is going on. Though for a starter, a 1V drop on a 2.2V diode is way more light loss than a 1V drop on a 3.2V. Not saying they are wired that way, but still, the 3.2V diode has a much wider voltage variability before it winks out.

Comment: i gave a set of auto-cycle multi-color fairy lights that when underpowered via PWM lights up the blue first, then green, but each "bulb" is wired in paralleled. i'm curious too.

Comment: @AliChen It is my understanding that the drop is the same regardless of the tech because of the energy barrier needed for the color. The higher the energy of the photon the larger the voltage drop needed

Comment: You are talking about direct LEDs. Today there are LED "lamps" based on the same one blue or near-UV LED emitter that is surrounded and excites different composition of luminophores. The LED is the same, colors differ by different luminophore. http://www.intematix.com/uploads/Catalogs/Phosphor-Brochure.pdf